# How to read iframe with jquery or asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I could not read this website iframe
//Need to enter here before
http://kktc.hititbet.com/SportFixtures.html?sportTypeId=1

How to asp.net or jquery read this iframe ?

```
<div>
    <iframe frameborder="0" name="cbox1419518838172" src="http://kktc.hititbet.com/SportFixturesDetLoad.html?home=Avustralya&amp;away=Kuveyt&amp;id=1502708" class="cboxIframe"></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and make changes iframe by using jquery you can use .content() method of jquery.

Check the example;

1- Add id to iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="frameDemo" name="cbox1419518838172"   src="http://kktc.hititbet.com/SportFixturesDetLoad.html?home=Avustralya&amp;away=Kuveyt&amp;id=1502708"     class="cboxIframe"></iframe>
```

2- script side

```
<script>
 $( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( "a" ).css( "background-color", "#BADA55" );
</script>
```